# Is buying co-workers lunches(reimbursed by them) taxable?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

Every day, I go out and buy 10 people lunches and they pay me back.  I mostly break even, but may come out a couple dollars ahead.  Do I need to claim this on my taxes?

Thanks

Comment: When you 'mostly' break even, are you coming up short? If over time it's really a wash, there's no issue at all.

Comment: its mostly a couple dollars ahead

Comment: Is there an expectation that it will even out later?  Or that it's a gift?  Or that they are paying for your time?  Or do they not realize they're overpaying?

Comment: And when you 'go out' is there a car ride and cost of gas?

Comment: Wait, so 250 work days times $X average overpayments a day, does that mean you're bringing in three figures in overages?

Comment: There is gas.. that's why people might give a dollar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a practical matter, you can ignore it.  As a legal matter, it's complicated but you can arguably ignore it.

The general rule under [IRC §61](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/61) is an incredibly broad conception of income, subject to specific carve-outs.  If they're paying you a dollar to go grab food, then that's income - same as the tip you pay the pizza guy.  But as with all tips, it's under the table ("undocumented income") and incredibly easy to conceal.  Such concealment is not in full compliance with the law, of course, but is nevertheless widespread.

If, however, they are paying you overage as a gift (which is suspiciously timed, given that the gifts coincide with you providing service), then that is excluded from income under [§102](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/102).  The gift tax ramifications are ignored, since it's well below the threshold where that becomes an obligation.

You might be able to construct some sort of argument where the overages today are offset in the future, so everybody comes out basically ahead.  If we were talking serious money, then such a loose system with no documentation would be ridiculous.  But at these levels it's not worth the audit it would take.  You might be able to slide on this shaky ground.

In the future, you may be able to avoid this problem by keeping the overages in a dedicated place (or keeping a running tally of the existing overage) and periodically  charging people less, to spend down the overage.  Or, more directly, by giving back exact change.  You could also dedicate all the overages to throwing a small party or splitting food with your co-workers (coffee, cookies, whatever).

You do not "need" to report this income.  Nobody else is submitting a 1099 or W-2, nor are they claiming deductions of their overages as tips or fees paid to you.  The money is invisible to the IRS.  So it would be easy to "cheat" and not report it.  But the tax on the overages is quite low, so not very painful to report.  It is also formally your obligation to report it, [**as the IRS says**](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Reporting-Miscellaneous-Income).  It would go on Form 1040, Line 21.

Comment: well we do use a computer to keep track of what people owe and what they pay, just to make ordering lunch easier so we could run a report and see what the profit was.. cool. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Because (I assume) that any amount you end up ahead is small you do not have to declare it. In fact the IRS deals with this sort of thing around "de minimis" fringe benefits.

http://www.irs.gov/Government-Entities/Federal,-State-&-Local-Governments/De-Minimis-Fringe-Benefits

I would assume the situation you described fits in this regulation.

Comment: one more thing is using a credit card.  they pay me via square and I pay the restaurant via card to get miles. Is the IRS going to care that there are all these purchases and deposits?

Comment: The instinct here is a good one.  But de minimis fringe benefits are paid by the employer, not by co-workers.  [IRC §132](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/132).  It wouldn't apply to overpaying from co-workers for lunches.